# Angular 6 to Spring boot rest service CORS issue

Tags: rest, spring-boot, cors, angular6

I have create an angular 6 app Deployed it on AWS S3 bucket as a static web hosting. 
From the backend side I have create a spring boot application which is exposing rest services and have annotation on controller and method level of CroosOrigin. It is also deployed on AWS tomcat EC2 instance.

When I try to click a button in angular app, it tries to call deployed spring rest web service. At console I m getting CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

When I try to call these services by Postman, It works fine. I have added a chrome extension for CORS in my chrome.

Anyone can help me why it not working when I try to call same service from angular app.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add such filter class to your spring boot application:

```
@Component
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Host, Referer, Connection, User-Agent, authorization, sw-useragent, sw-version");

        // Just REPLY OK if request method is OPTIONS for CORS (pre-flight)
        if ( req.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS") ) {
            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            return;
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {} 
}
```

Comment: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot, you can enable global `CORS` is to declare a `@Configuration` class `CorsConfig` class with defining @Bean `WebMvcConfigurer` with overriding `addCorsMappings`

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE").allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Or define a `MvcConfig` Class with implements`WebMvcConfigurer` then override `addCorsMappings`. like below:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
         registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE").allowedOrigins("*")
                            .allowedHeaders("*");
                }
            };
        }
}
```

Comment: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Can you please show me your http configuration class